# Pre-hashed string keys for faster Python dictionaries lookup?

Tags: python, string, optimization, hash, dictionary

How can I instruct python to store, internally, a pre-hashed version of my strings, so that it will use that value when I perform dict/set lookups using my string as a key?

I remember reading about it some weeks ago, but can't find it in python docs at the moment :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String interning is probably what you're thinking of.

See [`sys.intern` in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern)

See [`intern` in Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern)

Comment: Note that you probably don't need to use this; the hash of a string is computed once and cached, and string literals are always interned.

Comment: Yes, I found it just before looking at your answer. Bad thing is it requires the dictionary keys to also have been interned, and the dictionaries I'm using come from a third party package.

Comment: "string literals are always interned:" does this also apply to old python 2.5?

Comment: Strings are interned as part of the process of parsing and loading a .py or .pyc file.  If you want to know specific implementation details for sure for a particular version, you'll need to delve into the source, but for a rough empiric example you can do: `a = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'`; `b = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'`; `id(a) == id(b)`.  If the strings are interned, they'll have the same id.  You can also simply profile your code to see if interning actually helps.

Comment: Interesting, it works for all these cases: `a = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'; b = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'; id(a) == id(b)`, `a='aaaa'; b='a'*4; id(a)==id(b)`, or even `a='aaaa'; b='a%s' % 'aaa'; id(a)==id(b)`